# I am trying to access localhost:8080 but it is showing me I need to enter user name and pass word.I am working on spring boot API

Tags: spring-boot, server, linkedin-api

[image]

Is there any username & password for localhost:8080.

I tried with username-tomcat and password-tomcat,but did not work.

> > > > I am trying to do a project on spring social Linkedin signin,using spring boot API. If is there is any project which i can refer to solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check your username and password in tomcat-users.xml

Comment: I checked . Username is tomcat and password is also tomcat. I tried it bt didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Have you got @EnableWebSecurity configured in your Spring Boot app ?

If you haven't configured anything else the user defaults to "user" and a random, per boot time password is printed out in the logs. Search for this in the logs:

"Using default security password"

Explained in the reference docs [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-security)